# TFS api how to get default area of project

Tags: c#

i am geting project areas in following code but how can i get the default araea of a tfs project

Quick help will be very appreciated

```
 foreach (Node area in teamProject.AreaRootNodes)
 {
  foreach (Node item in area.ChildNodes)
   {

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's isn't a default area for a project per-se, only an area for a team, a default team is created for your Team Project, so **My Team Project** will have a a team called **My Team Project** (or similar) and that will have an default area path.

Then you can do something like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = GetServer("<server_uri>");
string projectUri = GetProject(collection, "<project_name");

var configSvc = collection.GetService<TeamSettingsConfigurationService>();
var configs = configSvc.GetTeamConfigurationsForUser(new[] { projectUri });

foreach (TeamConfiguration config in configs)
{
    // Output some basic team info.
    Console.WriteLine("Team name: {0}", config.TeamName);
    Console.WriteLine("Team ID: {0}", config.TeamId);
    Console.WriteLine("Is default team: {0}", config.IsDefaultTeam);

    // Access the actual configuration settings.
    TeamSettings ts = config.TeamSettings;

    // Output the information on the teams iterations.
    Console.WriteLine("Product backlog: {0}", ts.BacklogIterationPath);
    Console.WriteLine("Current iteration: {0}", ts.CurrentIterationPath);

    Console.WriteLine("Team iteration paths:");

    foreach (string path in settings.IterationPaths)
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", path);
}
```

Taken from [Ivan Popek's blog](http://blog.johnsworkshop.net/tfs11-api-reading-the-team-configuration-iterations-and-areas/)